# Angular: Call method from directive in component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

i am trying to call method from directive.
Lets say i have directive
myDirective.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[something]',
})
export class myDirective implements OnInit {
....
public myMethod(){
console.log(it works)
}
....
}
```

and component.ts (this is what i found but on this.directive i get error object is possibly null)

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '....html',
  styleUrls: ['....css'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(myDirective) directive = null

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClickFunction() {
    return (
      this.directive.myMethod();
    );
  }
}
```

How can i call this method in component?

Comment: The directive can actually be null, so you must always check whether it has a value: `this.directive?.myMethod();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run like this

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '....html',
  styleUrls: ['....css'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(myDirective) directive;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClickFunction() {
    return (
      this.directive?.myMethod()
    );
  }
}
```

In tsconfig.json add

```
"strictPropertyInitialization":false,
```